# Issue with application resolution

Tags: windows, display, resolution

I have issue with program that has fixed resolution (full screen) and can not be changed.

Resolution of the application is 1366x768

I want to use the program on windows 10 tablet that has resolution 1280x800, but don't have full view of the app because of incompatibile resolution

My question is:

Is there app that can convert resolution (render) to smaller resolution?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't if the program cannot actually work with different resolutions.